# Do I need to keep an icon pack installed after using the icon in Nova Launcher?

Tags: app-icons, nova-launcher, icon-packs

- I installed an icon pack
- Used on icon from the pack as folder icon in Nova Launcher
- All other icons in 20MB pack are useless

Do I need to keep the icon pack installed on my phone in order to keep using that icon in Nova Launcher? Or did Nova copy the icon to its data, and I can safely uninstall the pack?

The question's scope excludes workarounds, such as extracting individual icons from a pack. It's a good idea but for a different question.

Comment: Was using Nova a year ago and uninstalled icon packs after choosing what I wanted. Icons remained as desired but can't say where they are stored in Nova